# Two way binding for checkbox inside an accordion not workiing

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, checkbox

In my angular 1.5 html5 application, I have an accordion group and inside it's body I have Couple of check-boxes. Since direct scope binding will not work inside accordion, I'm using ng-click event as attached[image: ng-click instead of direct model binding].

This works as expected, I'm getting click events with correct value.

I have another reset button on screen, when user clicks this button I have to reset all filters including the checkbox inside the accordion. Even after I reset the model value to false, checkbox still shows as checked. I know this is because the binding is not there.

How can I update the checkbox value from javascript. Is there any angular way. I'm not a big fan of JQuery.

Regards,
Nixon

Comment: can you post a working fiddle or plunker?

Comment: I suspect something is wrong with the code somewhere.  Did you check the console for any error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We faced a similar issue with the data bindings while using accordian.
Instead of using directly model variable, we created an object of it.
For eg, instead of using $scope.includeLocalParties, try using $scope.checkbox.includeLocalParties.

Also initialize it in your controller. Something like this:
    $scope.checkbox = { includeLocalParties : false};

Hope it helps!